# Create a dictionary which saves its data to file

Tags: python, beginner, object-oriented, python-3.x

**Task:**

The task requires creating a class (say, `ConfigDict`) which inherits from the `dict` class.

It is supposed to save its keys and values in a file.
If a file does not exist, the instance of `ConfigDict` should be able to create it.

**Examples:**

For instance, the following code:

```
fh=open("config.txt","w")
fh.write("key1 = 5\n")
fh.write("key2 = 3\n")
fh.close()
cd=ConfigDict("config.txt")
cd.items()
```

would generate an output `dict_items([('key1', '5'), ('key2', '3')])`.

If a file does not exists, it should be possible for the instance to create it and save its data inside it.

```
dd=ConfigDict("test.txt")
dd["keyA"] = 'testA'
dd["keyB"] = 'testB'
dd.items()
```

The above lines would produce `dict_items([('keyA', 'testA'), ('keyB', 'testB')])` (and a `print` message).

**My attempt:**

I will greatly appreciate any comments.

```
class ConfigDict(dict):
    def __init__(self,file):
        self.file = file

        try: #check if file exists
            with open(self.file,"r+") as fh:
                for line in fh:
                    key, item = line.replace(" ", "").rstrip().split("=")
                    dict.__setitem__(self,key,item)

        except: 
            print("creating "+file)
            fh=open(self.file,"w")
            fh.close()


    def __setitem__(self,key,item):
        dict.__setitem__(self,key,item) #to avoid infinite loop
        lines = open(self.file).read().splitlines()

        for index, line in enumerate(lines):
            if line.replace(" ", "").rstrip().split("=")[0] == key:
               lines[index] = str(key)+" = "+str(item)
            else:
                lines.append(str(key)+" = "+str(item))

        open(self.file,'w').write('\n'.join(lines))
```

**Corrected version**

```
import os

class ConfigDict(dict):
    def __init__(self,file):
        self.file = file
        if os.path.isfile(self.file):
            with open(self.file,"r") as fh:
                for line in fh:
                    key, item = line.replace(" ", "").rstrip().split("=")
                    dict.__setitem__(self,key,item)

    def __setitem__(self,key,item):
        dict.__setitem__(self,key,item)            
        with open(self.file, 'w') as save_file:
            for key, value in self.items():
                save_file.write("{} = {}\n".format(key, value))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### bugs:

1. Your implementation of `__setitem__()` does not to add a line
   if the key does not exist in the file yet.

### other issues:

1. There is no need to create the file if it does not exist in
   `__init__()`, as `open(..., 'w')` in `__setattr__()` will create
   it for you.
2. It is gennerally not a good idea to print from a data class
   (i.e. `print("creating "+file)`) as this makes the class unuseable for
   programs that use stdout.
3. Iterating over a file in python automatically splits on lines so

   ```
   lines = open(self.file).read().splitlines()
   for index, line in enumerate(lines):
   ```

   could be written as

   ```
   for index, line in enumerate(open(self.file)):
   ```

   (like you did in `__init__()`)
4. If you are going to completly rewrite the file on every
   `__setitem__()`, there is no point in reading the file first, as this
   takes more time and is harder to read. here is an example
   `__setitem__()`:

   ```
   def __setitem__(self,key,item):
       dict.__setitem__(self,key,item) #to avoid infinite loop

       with open(self.file, 'w') as save_file:
           for key, value in self.items():
               save_file.write("{} = {}\n".format(key, value))
   ```

Comment: Thanks, the code will be much simpler. Regarding point 1, while I'm aware that `open(...,'w')` creates a file, if the `try` statement seemed to be a reasonable choice. If a file exists, one can set the keys and values. If it does not exist, create it and do nothing else.

Comment: My point is that the file will be created anyways in `__setattr__()` so there is no reason to create it in `__init__()`. I have edited my answer to hopefully reflect this better.

Comment: Ok, I think i get it:-).

Comment: You could also open the file in append mode and only perform a full rewrite in `__delitem__`.

Comment: Oh and please, close the file in `__setitem__`. Preferably using a `with` statement.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger yes, closing the file is a good idea, thanks. The append mode - can't comprehend how we could benefit from it.

Comment: @GregoryRut instead of writing the whole file at each `__setitem__`, just write the last entry, it will take less time. Duplicate entries are taken care off just fine when reading the file. Special care has to be taken when deleting entries, hence the proposal to rewrite the file on `__delitem__`.